# How to replace navigation bar with section header

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I currently have a setup where the navigation bar disappears with scroll "into" the status bar, is there any way to program the section header so that its placed right under the status bar and replace the navigation bar?

Comment: I can't quite visualize what you're aiming for, but would setting the contentInset of your UITableView to 20px (the height of the status bar) work?

Answer (score 0):

When you lay out your view in Interface builder, your UITableView or scrollview should be placed behind the navigation bar. The top of your scrollable view should end at the bottom of the status bar.

When the viewLoads for your scrollable view, you should set the contentOffset of the tableview by 44px. This will make your content appear correctly and not underneath the navigation bar, but when you scroll up and the navigation bar disappears, you'll be able to see the content in its place. And section headers should stick just below the status bar, until another section header pushes it out of the way.

Graphically, if you want your section headers to fill the same space as your navigation bar, just make them 44px tall.

Answer (score -1):

Not this is good design but if you really want to one in elegant would be to offset the view by 64px. Many tutorials online on how to do it.